# redirect query string to another query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to 301 redirect a query string to another query string, but everything I am trying seems to be failing.

I am trying to accomplish this:

http://www.example.com/something?_dog *to redirect to* http://www.example.com/something?_cat
http://www.example.com/page1?_dog *to redirect to* http://www.example.com/page1?_cat
http://www.example.com/aboutus?_dog *to redirect to* http://www.example.com/aboutus?_cat

and thousands of other pages, so i need to keep the current url/directory etc but just redirect it to use a different query string. they will all be "?_dog" going to "?_cat"

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_dog$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?_cat [L,R=302]
```